# How can I animate a SwiftUI view based on the change of a TextEditor's text?

Tags: animation, swiftui

My app has a SwiftUI View that contains both a TextEditor to collect a log entry and a List containing past entries.

When the text editor has a non-empty string, a button is presented to process the entry, add it to the data populating the list, and reset the TextEditor. Presently the button appears suddenly whenever text is typed, and I would love to animate that more smoothly, perhaps by fading in the opacity or scaling up the button. However, I can't figure out where to enter that animation.

```
   @State var newEntryString = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack{
                Text("Create a new log entry.")
                    .padding()
                TextEditor(text: $newEntryString)
                    .cornerRadius(3.0)
                    .padding()
                    .border(Color.gray, width: 1)
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, idealWidth: 100, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, idealHeight: 100, maxHeight: 150, alignment: .center)
                                
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    if !newEntryString.isEmpty{

                        Button(action: {
                            addEntry()
                        }) {
                            Text("Add Entry")
                        }.buttonStyle(JournalButtonStyle())
                        .animation(Animation.default.speed(1))
                    }
                }
                
                Divider()
                
                List {
                    ForEach(entrys) { item in
                        Text(item.timestamp!, formatter: entryFormatter).font(.footnote)
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            .padding(.bottom, -10)
                        Text((item.entryString!))
                    }
                    .onDelete(perform: deleteEntrys)
                }.onTapGesture {
                    UIApplication.shared.endEditing()
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use animation on container, like

```
HStack {
    Spacer()
    if !newEntryString.isEmpty{

        Button(action: {
            addEntry()
        }) {
            Text("Add Entry")
        }.buttonStyle(JournalButtonStyle())
    }
}.animation(Animation.default.speed(1))     // << here !!
```

Comment: T!hanks for putting me on the right path. It also helped me understand that I needed to place it on the other view affected by the animation—the List further down. Placing the .animation modifier on both those views worked perfectly.